# How can I use nginx as a dynamic load balancing proxy server on Bluemix?

Tags: nginx, containers, ibm-cloud, load-balancing, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to run an application on the bluemix container service. I am using nginx as a proxy webserver and load balancer.

I have found an image that uses docker events to automatically detect new web servers and adds those to the nginx configuration dynamically:

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

But for this to work, I think the container needs to connect  to a docker socket. I am not very familiar with docker and I dont know exactly what this does, but essentially it is necessary so that the image can listen to docker events.

The run command from the image documentation is the following:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

I have not been able to run this in the container service, as it does not find the `/var/run/docker.sock` file on the host.

The bluemix documentation has a [tutorial explaining how to do load balancing with nginx](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_compose_intro.html#container_compose_loadbalance). But it requires a "hard coded" list of web servers in the nginx configuration.

I was wondering how I could run the nginx-proxy image so that web instances are detected automatically?

Comment: I added the containers tag because that is what the Bluemix containers development team follows. Had to remove the sockets tag to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containers service on Bluemix doesn't expose that docker socket (not surprising, it would be a security risk to the compute host).  A couple of alternate ways to accomplish what you want:

- something like amalgam8 or consul, which is basically doing just that
- similar, but self written - have a shared volume, and then each
  container on startup adds a file to that shared volume saying what it
  is, plus its private ip.  nginx container has a watch on the shared
  volume, and reloads when those change. (more work than amalgam8 or
  consul, but perhaps more control)